# What does the German word "Zerlegungsautomorphismus" translate to?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, translation-request, mathematical-german, hecke-characters

I would like to know if any of our German friends can translate that word for me.

*Zerlegung* is factorisation, isn't it? So what is factorisation automorphism?

This is taken from Deuring's paper “[Die Zetafunktion einer algebraischen Kurve vom Geschlechte Eins (vierte Mitteilung)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=89227)”. This is not the run of the mill question, hopefully it is still a valid question.

This is possibly the first time this term appears, although this is part 4 of a series of paper, so I'm not sure if he has used/defined it in the earlier parts.

> Wir betrachten den Fall, daß **p** in $k_1$ prim bleibt,
>   $$\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{P},\quad\mathbf{p}^{\varphi}=\mathbf{P}.$$
>   $\varphi$ ist dann Zerlegungsautomorphismus von $\mathbf{P}$ über $k$, also auch von $\mathbf{P}_{\Sigma}$ über dem Körper $P$ der rationalen Zahlen,
>   $$\mathbf{p}=\mathbf{P}_{\Sigma}\quad\text{oder}\quad\mathbf{p}^{\varphi}=\mathbf{P}.$$

Danke sehr!

Comment: Zerlegung could as well mean partitoining ...

Comment: But what would a partitioning automorphism mean though?

Comment: Dunno. Unfortunately I am not aware of Deuring's paper and that automorphism anyway (and this question is the only google hit :)

Comment: Haha, that was the reason I turned to SE!

Comment: I tried googling "Zerlegungsautomorphismus", which looks (to me) more like a German word than "Zerlegungautomorphism", but I got nothing useful.  My best guess is that it means an automorphism of some decomposition, i.e., a bijection that sends some decomposition (of something) to itself, but this is only a guess.

Comment: If no one answers, maybe provide a quote of a few sentences before the first time it is used in the paper.

Comment: Maybe "decomposition" instead? There is a decomposition group and a decomposition field. If the group is cyclic, then it'd make sense to call its generator a decomposition automorphism.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that *Zerlegungsgruppe* is commonly translated as *decomposition group*. It comes about when studying the splitting of prime ideals in a Galois extension of number fields. The Galois group acts (transitively) on the set of primes lying above a given one. The decomposition group of a prime of the bigger field is its stabilizer inside the Galois group.

Given this it stands to reason that *Zerlegungsautomorphismus* means: an element of the decomposition group, i.e. an automorphism of the bigger field that maps this prime to itself.

A related concept is that of *inertia group* (*Trägheitsgruppe* in German) - a subgroup of the decomposition group that induces the trivial automorphism to the residue class field. The hierarchy of ramification groups then resides inside the inertia group. I'm afraid I don't remember what they are called in German.

The same concepts appear in the study of function fields (of transcendence degree one) over a finite field. Dedekind domains and their fields of quotients being the common umbrella. This is apparently Deuring's theme.

Even in English texts the symbol $Z$ (resp. $T$) often stands for the decomposition group (resp. inertia group). I guess this is a tribute to the contributions of German number theorists. We can then identify $Z/T$ as the Galois group of the related extension of residue class fields. In the listed cases the residue class fields are finite, so $Z/T$ is then necessarily cyclic.

Comment: It is possible that (as @Jack Schmidt suggested) *Zerlegungsautomorphismus* has to be a generator of the decomposition group. We need more context and/or an expert to get more details.

Comment: The Galois group of the residue field extension is cyclic, and lifts to a cyclic-group-mod-$T$, yes. Frobenius.